# difference between the destination IP of a crafted packet and the destination ip argument of raw socket send()

Tags: networking, network-programming, raw-sockets

I want to use raw socket to send a packet.

if I create a IP packet(icmp, tcp or udp packet), then the source and destination IP is in the IP packet. now I want to send it via the following lines:

```
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dst_ip);
    sendto(sd, packet, 60, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
```

of course, the `dst_ip` should be the same as the destination IP in the packet.

I'm wondering what happens if the `dst_ip` is not the same as the destination IP in the packet. It seems to me that the `dst_ip` is used to decide for which NIC should be used to send the packet. while the destination IP in the crafted packet is not changed by `dst_ip` and will be processed by in-network routers.

is my understanding correct or not? are there any other differences?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for BSD is a comment in the source code for `rip_output():`<sup>1</sup> "If the user handed us a complete packet, use it. Otherwise, allocate an mbuf for a header and fill it in" [i.e., from the address provided to `sendto()`].

For other systems you're going to have to read some kernel source code.

1. G.R. Wright & W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* vol II: The Implementation, pp.1057-1062.

Comment: I don't find a strong relation between your answer with my question